# Java SaxParser XML

Tags: java, xml, enums, factory, saxparser

this is my first question here. do not judge strictly:) I'm parsing a file with the dim extension of the xml format, in fact, so I chose SAXparser. the problem is probably architectural or I don’t know how to call it correctly. in general, if you describe: there is a list of tags that I need to pull out and, in accordance with them, create objects, assign values ​​​​to their fields, which the parser will pull out as strings from certain tags. in accordance with the tags I need, I have implemented classes with which I need to create objects in the startElement method, after that in endElement I need to assign the appropriate strings to this object. The crux of the problem is that I can't figure out how I can avoid a lot of code in the SaxParserHandler class, including a lot of if/else in the startElement and endElement methods. tried to use enum and factory pattern, but all in vain. example of my current code in SaxParserHandler:

public class SaxParserHandler extends DefaultHandler {

```
private Dataset_Id dataset_id = null;

private StringBuilder data = null;

private Dataset_Frame dataset_frame = null;

private String MetadataId = "Metadata_Id";
private String dataset_name_tag = "DATASET_NAME";
private String dataset_frame_tag = "Dataset_Frame";

private Vertex vertex = null;
private List<Vertex> vertices = null;

private String vertex_tag = "Vertex";
private String FRAME_LON = "FRAME_LON";
private String FRAME_LAT = "FRAME_LAT";
private String FRAME_X = "FRAME_X";
private String FRAME_Y = "FRAME_Y";
private String FRAME_ROW = "FRAME_ROW";
private String FRAME_COL = "FRAME_COL";

private Source_Information source_information = null;
private Scene_Source scene_source = null;

private String source_info_tag = "Source_Information";
private String source_id_tag = "SOURCE_ID";
private String scene_source_tag = "Scene_Source";
private String imaging_date_tag = "IMAGING_DATE";
private String imaging_time_tag = "IMAGING_TIME";
private String mission_tag = "MISSION";
private String mission_index_tag = "MISSION_INDEX";
private String instrument_tag = "INSTRUMENT";
private String satellite_incidence_angle_tag = "SATELLITE_INCIDENCE_ANGLE";
private String viewing_angle_tag = "VIEWING_ANGLE";
private String sun_azimuth_tag = "SUN_AZIMUTH";
private String sun_elevation_tag = "SUN_ELEVATION";
private String theoretical_resolution_tag = "THEORETICAL_RESOLUTION";

private Coordinate_Reference_System coordinate_reference_system = null;
private Horizontal_CS horizontal_cs = null;

private String Coordinate_Reference_System_Tag = "Coordinate_Reference_System";
private String Horizontal_CS_Tag = "Horizontal_CS";
private String HORIZONTAL_CS_CODE_TAG = "HORIZONTAL_CS_CODE";
private String HORIZONTAL_CS_TYPE_TAG = "HORIZONTAL_CS_TYPE";
private String HORIZONTAL_CS_NAME_TAG = "HORIZONTAL_CS_NAME";

private Production production = null;
private Production_Facility production_facility = null;

private String Production_Tag = "Production";
private String DATASET_PRODUCTION_DATE_TAG = "DATASET_PRODUCTION_DATE";
private String PRODUCT_TYPE_TAG = "PRODUCT_TYPE";
private String PRODUCT_INFO_TAG = "PRODUCT_INFO";
private String JOB_ID_TAG = "JOB_ID";
private String Production_Facility_Tag = "Production_Facility";
private String SOFTWARE_NAME_TAG = "SOFTWARE_NAME";
private String SOFTWARE_VERSION_TAG = "SOFTWARE_VERSION";
private String PROCESSING_CENTER_TAG = "PROCESSING_CENTER";

private Raster_Encoding raster_encoding = null;

private String Raster_Encoding_Tag = "Raster_Encoding";
private String DATA_TYPE_TAG = "DATA_TYPE";
private String NBITS_TAG = "NBITS";
private String BYTEORDER_TAG = "BYTEORDER";
private String BANDS_LAYOUT_TAG = "BANDS_LAYOUT";

private Data_Processing data_processing = null;

private String Data_Processing_Tag = "Data_Processing";
private String PROCESSING_LEVEL_TAG = "PROCESSING_LEVEL";
private String GEOMETRIC_PROCESSING_TAG = "GEOMETRIC_PROCESSING";
private String RADIOMETRIC_PROCESSING_TAG = "RADIOMETRIC_PROCESSING";

private Data_Access data_access = null;
private Data_File_List data_file_list = null;

private String Data_Access_Tag = "Data_Access";
private String DATA_FILE_FORMAT_TAG = "DATA_FILE_FORMAT";
private String DATA_FILE_ORGANISATION_TAG = "DATA_FILE_ORGANISATION";
private String Data_File_List_Tag = "Data_File_List";
private String DATA_FILE_PATH_TAG = "DATA_FILE_PATH";

private Image_Display image_display = null;
private Band_Display_Order band_display_order = null;

private String Image_Display_Tag = "Image_Display";
private String Band_Display_Order_Tag = "Band_Display_Order";
private String RED_CHANNEL_TAG = "RED_CHANNEL";
private String GREEN_CHANNEL_TAG = "GREEN_CHANNEL";
private String BLUE_CHANNEL_TAG = "BLUE_CHANNEL";

private Data_Strip data_strip = null;

private Data_Strip_Identification data_strip_identification = null;
private Time_Stamp time_stamp = null;
private Ephemeris ephemeris = null;

private String Data_Strip_Tag = "Data_Strip";

private String Data_Strip_Identification_Tag = "Data_Strip_Identification";
private String DATA_STRIP_ID_TAG = "DATA_STRIP_ID";
private String SEGMENT_ID_TAG = "SEGMENT_ID";

private String Time_Stamp_Tag = "Time_Stamp";

private String REFERENCE_BAND_TAG = "REFERENCE_BAND";
private String REFERENCE_TIME_TAG = "REFERENCE_TIME";
private String REFERENCE_LINE_TAG = "REFERENCE_LINE";
private String LINE_PERIOD_TAG = "LINE_PERIOD";

private String Ephemeris_Tag = "Ephemeris";

private String SATELLITE_ALTITUDE_TAG = "SATELLITE_ALTITUDE";


@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    
    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase(dataset_name_tag))
            dataset_id = new Dataset_Id();
        else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase(dataset_frame_tag)) {
            dataset_frame = new Dataset_Frame();
        } else if (qName.equals(vertex_tag)) {
            vertex = new Vertex();
            if (vertices == null)
                vertices = new ArrayList<>();
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase(source_info_tag)) {
            source_information = new Source_Information();
        } else if (qName.equals(scene_source_tag)) {
            scene_source = new Scene_Source();
        } else if (qName.equals(Coordinate_Reference_System_Tag)) {
            coordinate_reference_system = new Coordinate_Reference_System();
        } else if (qName.equals(Horizontal_CS_Tag)) {
            horizontal_cs = new Horizontal_CS();
        } else if (qName.equals(Production_Tag)) {
            production = new Production();
        } else if (qName.equals(Production_Facility_Tag)) {
            production_facility = new Production_Facility();
        } else if (qName.equals(Raster_Encoding_Tag)) {
            raster_encoding = new Raster_Encoding();
        } else if (qName.equals(Data_Processing_Tag)) {
            data_processing = new Data_Processing();
        } else if (qName.equals(Data_Access_Tag)) {
            data_access = new Data_Access();
        } else if (qName.equals(Data_File_List_Tag)) {
            data_file_list = new Data_File_List();
        }else if (qName.equals(Image_Display_Tag)) {
            image_display = new Image_Display();
        }else if (qName.equals(Band_Display_Order_Tag)) {
            band_display_order = new Band_Display_Order();
        }else if (qName.equals(Data_Strip_Tag)){
            data_strip = new Data_Strip();
        }else if (qName.equals(Data_Strip_Identification_Tag)) {
            data_strip_identification = new Data_Strip_Identification();
        }else if (qName.equals(Time_Stamp_Tag)) {
            time_stamp = new Time_Stamp();
        }else if (qName.equals(Ephemeris_Tag)) {
            ephemeris = new Ephemeris();
        }



    data = new StringBuilder();
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
    if (qName.equals(dataset_name_tag)) {
        dataset_id.setDataset_name(data.toString());
    } else if (qName.equals(FRAME_LON)) {
        vertex.setFRAME_LON(data.toString());
    } else if (qName.equals(FRAME_LAT)) {
        vertex.setFRAME_LAT(data.toString());
    } else if (qName.equals(FRAME_X)) {
        vertex.setFRAME_X(data.toString());
    } else if (qName.equals(FRAME_Y)) {
        vertex.setFRAME_Y(data.toString());
    } else if (qName.equals(FRAME_ROW)) {
        vertex.setFRAME_ROW(data.toString());
    } else if (qName.equals(FRAME_COL)) {
        vertex.setFRAME_COL(data.toString());
    } else if (qName.equals(vertex_tag)) {
        vertices.add(vertex);
    } else if (qName.equals(dataset_frame_tag)) {
        dataset_frame.setDataset_Frame(vertices);
    } else if (qName.equals(source_id_tag)) {
        source_information.setSource_id(data.toString());
    } else if (qName.equals(imaging_date_tag)) {
        scene_source.setIMAGING_DATE(data.toString());
    } else if (qName.equals(imaging_time_tag)) {
        scene_source.setIMAGING_TIME(data.toString());
    } else if (qName.equals(mission_tag)) {
        scene_source.setMISSION(data.toString());
    } else if (qName.equals(mission_index_tag)) {
        scene_source.setMISSION_INDEX(data.toString());
    } else if (qName.equals(instrument_tag)) {
        scene_source.setINSTRUMENT(data.toString());
    } else if (qName.equals(satellite_incidence_angle_tag)) {
        scene_source.setSATELLITE_INCIDENCE_ANGLE(data.toString());
    } else if (qName.equals(viewing_angle_tag)) {
        scene_source.setVIEWING_ANGLE(data.toString());
    } else if (qName.equals(sun_azimuth_tag)) {
        scene_source.setSUN_AZIMUTH(data.toString());
    } else if (qName.equals(sun_elevation_tag)) {
        scene_source.setSUN_ELEVATION(data.toString());
    } else if (qName.equals(theoretical_resolution_tag)) {
        scene_source.setTHEORETICAL_RESOLUTION(data.toString());
    } else if (qName.equals(source_info_tag)) {
        source_information.setScene_source(scene_source);
    } else if (qName.equals(HORIZONTAL_CS_TYPE_TAG)) {
        horizontal_cs.setHORIZONTAL_CS_TYPE(data.toString());
    } else if (qName.equals(HORIZONTAL_CS_NAME_TAG)) {
        horizontal_cs.setHORIZONTAL_CS_NAME(data.toString());
    } else if (qName.equals(HORIZONTAL_CS_CODE_TAG)) {
        horizontal_cs.setHORIZONTAL_CS_CODE(data.toString());
    } else if (qName.equals(Horizontal_CS_Tag)) {
        coordinate_reference_system.setHorizontal_cs(horizontal_cs);
    } else if (qName.equals(DATASET_PRODUCTION_DATE_TAG)) {
        production.setDATASET_PRODUCTION_DATE(data.toString());
    } else if (qName.equals(PRODUCT_TYPE_TAG)) {
        production.setPRODUCT_TYPE(data.toString());
    } else if (qName.equals(PRODUCT_INFO_TAG)) {
        production.setPRODUCT_INFO(data.toString());
    } else if (qName.equals(JOB_ID_TAG)) {
        production.setJOB_ID(data.toString());
    } else if (qName.equals(SOFTWARE_NAME_TAG)) {
        production_facility.setSOFTWARE_NAME(data.toString());
    } else if (qName.equals(SOFTWARE_VERSION_TAG)) {
        production_facility.setSOFTWARE_VERSION(data.toString());
    } else if (qName.equals(PROCESSING_CENTER_TAG)) {
        production_facility.setPROCESSING_CENTER(data.toString());
    } else if (qName.equals(Production_Tag)) {
        production.setProduction_facility(production_facility);
    } else if (qName.equals(DATA_TYPE_TAG)) {
        raster_encoding.setDATA_TYPE(data.toString());
    } else if (qName.equals(NBITS_TAG)) {
        raster_encoding.setNBITS(data.toString());
    } else if (qName.equals(BYTEORDER_TAG)) {
        raster_encoding.setBYTEORDER(data.toString());
    } else if (qName.equals(BANDS_LAYOUT_TAG)) {
        raster_encoding.setBANDS_LAYOUT(data.toString());
    } else if (qName.equals(PROCESSING_LEVEL_TAG)) {
        data_processing.setPROCESSING_LEVEL(data.toString());
    } else if (qName.equals(GEOMETRIC_PROCESSING_TAG)) {
        data_processing.setGEOMETRIC_PROCESSING(data.toString());
    } else if (qName.equals(RADIOMETRIC_PROCESSING_TAG)) {
        data_processing.setRADIOMETRIC_PROCESSING(data.toString());
    } else if (qName.equals(DATA_FILE_FORMAT_TAG)) {
        data_access.setDATA_FILE_FORMAT(data.toString());
    } else if (qName.equals(DATA_FILE_ORGANISATION_TAG)) {
        data_access.setDATA_FILE_ORGANISATION(data.toString());
    } else if (qName.equals(DATA_FILE_PATH_TAG)) {
        data_file_list.setDATA_FILE_PATH(data.toString());
    } else if (qName.equals(Data_File_List_Tag)) {
        data_access.setData_file_lists(data_file_list);
    }else if (qName.equals(RED_CHANNEL_TAG)) {
        band_display_order.setRED_CHANNEL(data.toString());
    }else if (qName.equals(GREEN_CHANNEL_TAG)) {
        band_display_order.setGREEN_CHANNEL(data.toString());
    }else if (qName.equals(BLUE_CHANNEL_TAG)) {
        band_display_order.setBLUE_CHANNEL(data.toString());
    }else if (qName.equals(Band_Display_Order_Tag)) {
        image_display.setBand_display_orders(band_display_order);
    }else if (qName.equals(DATA_STRIP_ID_TAG)){
        data_strip_identification.setDATA_STRIP_ID(data.toString());
    }else if (qName.equals(SEGMENT_ID_TAG)) {
        data_strip_identification.setSEGMENT_ID(data.toString());
    }else if (qName.equals(Data_Strip_Identification_Tag)) {
        data_strip.setData_strip_identification(data_strip_identification);
    }else if (qName.equals(REFERENCE_BAND_TAG)) {
        time_stamp.setREFERENCE_BAND(data.toString());
    }else if (qName.equals(REFERENCE_TIME_TAG)){
        time_stamp.setREFERENCE_TIME(data.toString());
    }else if (qName.equals(REFERENCE_LINE_TAG)) {
        time_stamp.setREFERENCE_LINE(data.toString());
    }else if (qName.equals(LINE_PERIOD_TAG)) {
        time_stamp.setLINE_PERIOD(data.toString());
    }else if (qName.equals(Time_Stamp_Tag)) {
        data_strip.setTime_stamp(time_stamp);
    }else if (qName.equals(SATELLITE_ALTITUDE_TAG)) {
        ephemeris.setSATELLITE_ALTITUDE(data.toString());
    }else if (qName.equals(Ephemeris_Tag)) {
        data_strip.setEphemerises(ephemeris);
    }
}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {

    data.append(new String(ch, start, length));

}

Root root = new Root();

public Root getRoot() {
    root.setDataset_id(dataset_id);
    root.setDataset_frame(dataset_frame);
    root.setSource_information(source_information);
    root.setCoordinate_reference_systems(coordinate_reference_system);
    root.setProductions(production);
    root.setRaster_encodings(raster_encoding);
    root.setData_processings(data_processing);
    root.setData_accesses(data_access);
    root.setImage_displays(image_display);
    root.setData_strips(data_strip);
    return root;
}
```

}

part of dim file sample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Dimap_Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Metadata_Id>
        <METADATA_FORMAT version="1.1">DIMAP</METADATA_FORMAT>
    </Metadata_Id>
    <Dataset_Id>
        <DATASET_NAME>KM000604MI_017_MUL_L1G</DATASET_NAME>
        <DATASET_TN_PATH href="KM000604MI_017_MUL_L1G_tn.jpg"/>
        <DATASET_QL_PATH href="KM000604MI_017_MUL_L1G_ql.jpg"/>
    </Dataset_Id>
    <Production>
        <DATASET_PRODUCER_NAME/>
        <DATASET_PRODUCTION_DATE>2015-09-28</DATASET_PRODUCTION_DATE>
        <PRODUCT_TYPE/>
    </Production>
    <Dataset_Use>
        <DATASET_CONTENT/>
    </Dataset_Use>
    <Data_Processing>
        <GEOMETRIC_PROCESSING/>
        <Processing_Parameter>
            <PROC_PARAMETER_DESC>SOFTWARE</PROC_PARAMETER_DESC>
            <PROC_PARAMETER_VALUE>Keystone 3.8.9.FINAL.</PROC_PARAMETER_VALUE>
        </Processing_Parameter>
    </Data_Processing>
    <Coordinate_Reference_System>
        <GEO_TABLES>EPSG</GEO_TABLES>
        <Horizontal_CS>
            <HORIZONTAL_CS_CODE>EPSG:32642</HORIZONTAL_CS_CODE>
            <HORIZONTAL_CS_TYPE>PROJECTED</HORIZONTAL_CS_TYPE>
            <HORIZONTAL_CS_NAME>WGS 84 / UTM zone 42N</HORIZONTAL_CS_NAME>
            <Coordinate_Axis>
                <AXIS1_NAME>Easting</AXIS1_NAME>
                <AXIS2_NAME>Northing</AXIS2_NAME>
                <AXIS1_ORIENTATION>EAST</AXIS1_ORIENTATION>
                <AXIS2_ORIENTATION>NORTH</AXIS2_ORIENTATION>
            </Coordinate_Axis>
            <Projection>
                <PROJECTION_NAME>UTM zone 42N</PROJECTION_NAME>
                <PROJECTION_CODE>EPSG:16042</PROJECTION_CODE>
                <Projection_CT_Method>
                    <PROJECTION_CT_NAME>Transverse Mercator</PROJECTION_CT_NAME>
                    <PROJECTION_CT_CODE>EPSG:9807</PROJECTION_CT_CODE>
                    <Projection_Parameters>
                        <Projection_Parameter>
                            <PROJECTION_PARAMETER_NAME>Latitude_of_natural_origin</PROJECTION_PARAMETER_NAME>
                            <PROJECTION_PARAMETER_VALUE unit="DEG">0.0</PROJECTION_PARAMETER_VALUE>
                        </Projection_Parameter>
                        <Projection_Parameter>
                            <PROJECTION_PARAMETER_NAME>Longitude_of_natural_origin</PROJECTION_PARAMETER_NAME>
                            <PROJECTION_PARAMETER_VALUE unit="DEG">69.0</PROJECTION_PARAMETER_VALUE>
                        </Projection_Parameter>
                        <Projection_Parameter>
                            <PROJECTION_PARAMETER_NAME>Scale_factor_at_natural_origin</PROJECTION_PARAMETER_NAME>
                            <PROJECTION_PARAMETER_VALUE>0.9996</PROJECTION_PARAMETER_VALUE>
                        </Projection_Parameter>
                        <Projection_Parameter>
                            <PROJECTION_PARAMETER_NAME>False_easting</PROJECTION_PARAMETER_NAME>
                            <PROJECTION_PARAMETER_VALUE unit="M">500000.0</PROJECTION_PARAMETER_VALUE>
                        </Projection_Parameter>
                        <Projection_Parameter>
                            <PROJECTION_PARAMETER_NAME>False_northing</PROJECTION_PARAMETER_NAME>
                            <PROJECTION_PARAMETER_VALUE unit="M">0.0</PROJECTION_PARAMETER_VALUE>
                        </Projection_Parameter>
                    </Projection_Parameters>
                </Projection_CT_Method>
            </Projection>
            <Geographic_CS>
                <GEOGRAPHIC_CS_NAME>WGS 84</GEOGRAPHIC_CS_NAME>
                <GEOGRAPHIC_CS_CODE>EPSG:4326</GEOGRAPHIC_CS_CODE>
                <Horizontal_Datum>
                    <HORIZONTAL_DATUM_NAME>World Geodetic System 1984</HORIZONTAL_DATUM_NAME>
                    <HORIZONTAL_DATUM_CODE>EPSG:6326</HORIZONTAL_DATUM_CODE>
                    <Ellipsoid>
                        <ELLIPSOID_NAME>WGS 84</ELLIPSOID_NAME>
                        <ELLIPSOID_CODE>EPSG:7030</ELLIPSOID_CODE>
                        <Ellipsoid_Parameters>
                            <ELLIPSOID_MAJOR_AXIS unit="M">6378137.0</ELLIPSOID_MAJOR_AXIS>
                            <ELLIPSOID_MINOR_AXIS unit="M">6356752.314245</ELLIPSOID_MINOR_AXIS>
                        </Ellipsoid_Parameters>
                    </Ellipsoid>
                    <Prime_Meridian>
                        <PRIME_MERIDIAN_NAME>Greenwich</PRIME_MERIDIAN_NAME>
                        <PRIME_MERIDIAN_CODE>EPSG:8901</PRIME_MERIDIAN_CODE>
                        <PRIME_MERIDIAN_OFFSET unit="DEG">0.0</PRIME_MERIDIAN_OFFSET>
                    </Prime_Meridian>
                </Horizontal_Datum>
            </Geographic_CS>
        </Horizontal_CS>
    </Coordinate_Reference_System>
```

Comment: Do you have a XSD for your XML file? It might be easier if you use jaxb.

Comment: no, unfortunately I only receive the file in this format

Comment: Can you share a sample of your xml?

Comment: Please share your XML. Depending of the complexity of it, it will help us guide you to the easiest solution. And you can create a XSD from a XML.

Comment: this is a link with two files, the similarity of which I have to parse

Comment: Include a sample in the question instead of external links.

Comment: sorry for the stupidity. i did it

Answer (score -1):

If you are open to use third party libraries, you might give [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) a try. Jsoup is actually a HTML-parser but is also able to parse XML. It provides IMHO an intuitive and simple [selector syntax](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) and [API](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) which you can use to get the elements you are interested in.

I am not realy sure what you are trying to achieve and didn't find all the tags from your code in the sample xml you provided. But to give you a simple starting point on how to use Jsoup, please see below snippet where I fetch the
`Production DATASET_PRODUCTION_DATE` and the `Projection_Parameters` from the sample xml:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.parser.Parser;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Example2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("path to your xml file"));
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(in, "UTF-8", "", Parser.xmlParser());

        String productionDate = doc.selectFirst("Production DATASET_PRODUCTION_DATE").text();
        System.out.println("PRODUCTION_DATE: " + productionDate);

        Elements projection_Parameters = doc.select("Projection_Parameter");

        projection_Parameters.forEach(param -> {
            String name  = param.selectFirst("PROJECTION_PARAMETER_NAME").text();
            String value = param.selectFirst("PROJECTION_PARAMETER_VALUE").text();
            System.out.printf("NAME: %s, VALUE: %s %n", name, value);
        });
    }
}
```

output:

```
PRODUCTION_DATE: 2015-09-28
NAME: Latitude_of_natural_origin, VALUE: 0.0 
NAME: Longitude_of_natural_origin, VALUE: 69.0 
NAME: Scale_factor_at_natural_origin, VALUE: 0.9996 
NAME: False_easting, VALUE: 500000.0 
NAME: False_northing, VALUE: 0.0
```

Instead of printing to console you could of course create directly your POJOs. If interested get Jsoup from Maven central

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
    <version>1.15.3</version>
</dependency>
```